# Windows Live Mail unable to open in links in Chrome (Windows 7)

Tags: google-chrome, email, windows-live-mail

I'm having a problem where whenever I open links from Windows Live Mail in Google Chrome the page loads indefinitely. It comes up with "untitled" and eventually shows a box asking if I want to kill the page or wait. I am unable to browse to other addresses through that or any other tab until I close and reopen the browser.

I have tested and WLM is able to open links in internet explorer if I change the associations, and other programs (MS Word is the example I tried) is able to open links in Chrome.

I have tried multiple different urls and all exhibit the same behavior (but work fine if copy/pasted in).

I have tried disabling all AV/Firewall functions, reinstalled Chrome, run a repair of Live Essentials, and changed program associations around a few times in case they're causing the issues.

All related software is up to date.

The whole thing is a bit of a black box, so I'm not really sure how to approach diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the compatibility mode of WLM to Vista SP2 so minimizing the window goes to the tray instead of the task bar, then WLM opens the link in Chrome in compatiblity mode also. To fix this, set Chrome to open in compatiblity mode for Win7 or whatever your OS is.